# Sorting object with null values underscore sortBy

Tags: javascript, sorting, null, underscore.js

I'm sorting my object by its property `ActivityOrder`, which will sometimes contain `null` values if the user has not explicitly stated an order which an activity should appear.

Since `null` will always appear top most in the sort (unless reversed), it messed up my sort.

The solution I came up with was to sort by the `id` if `activityOrder` was null since the ID will always be greater than the `activityOrder` within our application and then there is some logical order to the sort too.

```
var data = [{
        "id": 150,
        "name": "Andrew",
        "activityOrder": null
}, {
        "id": 151,
        "name": "Andrew",
        "activityOrder": null
}, {
        "id": 152,
        "name": "Andrew",
        "activityOrder": 1
}];


data = _.sortBy(data, function(o) {
        if (o.activityOrder === null)
            return o.id;
        return o.activityOrder
});

_.each(data, function(x) {
        $('#cnt').append("<tr><td>" + x.Name + " - Order " + x.activityOrder + "</td></tr>")
})
```

I had also tried amending the value if the `activityOrder` null to 99999999999 and resetting it back to null after doing whatever. I didn't like the idea of this one.

```
data = _.sortBy(data, function(o) {
        if (o.activityOrder === null)
            o.activityOrder = 99999999999;
        return o.activityOrder
});

//Do whatever

//Reset Activity Order back
_.each(d, function(o) {
        if (o.activityOrder === 99999999999) {
                o.activityOrder = null;
        }
});
```

How best would you sort an object array by a property which contains null values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [flapdoodle!](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flapdoodle)

```
if (o.activityOrder === null)
        o.activityOrder = 99999999999;
```

Dude, don't do this. Really.

---

#### Sorting idiom

- Javascript supports sorting pretty much as you'll see in other languages.
- Collections have sorting.
- Sort functions can take a function delegate for customized sorting.
- Typically, compare the desired values and return an integer that means less-than, equal-to, greater-than. Typically -1, 0, 1 respectively.
- handling `null` does not require converting it to a valid value in your set domain.
- **Read the documentation!**

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, a null can't really be sorted within a group of sortable objects. You'll end up with the nulls beside each other every time, where they lay is the question. I take it you wanted to sort the array WITHOUT looking at nulls? i.e.

`1, null, null, 10, 1, null, 73, 5`

should become

`1, null, null, 1, 5, null, 10, 73`

Is this what you want?

Edit: Woops I mistook this post for Java. Does Javascript offer a comparator interface or implementation? I suggest you look towards making your own sort algorithm to sort how you want, but excluding any comparisons on a proper `int` versus `null`.

Comment: Not particularly, I wanted the nulls to be treated as a "high number" when sorting by ascending. `1 , 2, 24, null, null` and a "low number" when descending. I think my method will be a fair solution to the problem within my application. I was just curious as to whether there were any hidden gems when dealing with them.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz Ah I understand. I think sorting with nulls at one end is easy, sorting with them at both ends based on a choice of desc/asc is the trickier part. I definitely think there's a way around the `99999...` variable swap.

Comment: Yep, just found it. If I just return 99999 or `Infinity` then that should solve it. The ascending / descending could be done with a simple function which takes an optional parameter `function sortObject(data, ascending=true)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a javascript function based on lodash's functions that allows the sort of array of objects with **null** and **undefined** always at the end (ascending and descending order) of the resulting array (copy).
It allows ordering on **sub-properties** (ex: 'parcel.purchaser.name')

```
function orderByWithNullsAtEnd(pArray: any[], pAttr: string, pReverse: boolean) {
  const partition = _.partition(pArray, (x) => !!_.get(x, pAttr, null));
  return _.concat(_.orderBy(partition[0], pAttr, (pReverse ? 'desc' : 'asc')), partition[1]);
}
```

The advantages of this solution are:

- genericity; that's work with all datatypes (of fields)
- put all the null (or undefined) at the end
- based on a well-known library (lodash)
- can be easily improve to do the same for empty string values